# how to get all keycloak users who can access to a specific resource

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I have a KC instance where I have some clients with the `Authorization` option enabled. All works well, but, acting as a client, I need this specific information: Given a certain resource with specific scopes I want the list of users who have accesse to this resource.

I've explored the available APIs multiple times without success. Is there a way to obtain this information or do I necessary need to extends KC capabilities with a dedicated SPI ?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible by Admin rest-API for finding a specific resource's all of user.

This steps
[image]

I am using Keycloak v18.0.2 (if use v19/v20, just remove `auth` in API endpoint)

#1 Get specific client uuid

```
GET {keycloak_url}/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/clients/{client-uuid}
```

#2 Get specific resource uuid

```
GET {keycloak_url}/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/clients/{client-uuid}/authz/resource-server/resource/{resource-uuid}
```

#3 Get specific permission of #2

```
GET {keycloak_url}/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/clients/{client-uuid}/authz/resource-server/resource/{resource-uuid}/permissions
```

#4 Get policy of #3
Get policy and permission list

```
GET {keycloak_url}/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/clients/{client-uuid}/authz/resource-server/policy
```

Get policy of specific permission

```
GET {keycloak_url}/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/clients/{client-uuid}/authz/resource-server/policy/{permission-uuid}/associatedPolicies
```

#5 Get user list of #4

```
GET {keycloak_url}/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/clients/{client-uuid}/authz/resource-server/policy/{policy-uuid}
```

The user list will return in body of response

```
{
    "id": {policy-uuid},
    "name": {policy-name},
    "config": {
        "users": "[array of {user-uuid}]"
    }
}
```

### Demo by UI

I will find all of user in `resource1` of `my-test` client.

[image]

It assosicated `permission1`
[image]

`permissions1` apply `policy1`
[image]

`policy`'s user two users
[image]

### Demo by API

Same step by APIs

Find client uuid

[image]

Find a specific resource uuid

[image]

Get specific resource

[image]

Get permission and policy list
[image]

Get associated policy for permission
[image]

Get user list for policy
[image]

That user uuid matched user list
[image]

So you can find `resource1`'s user are `user1` and `user3`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot. Keycloak authorization mechanism  examines only when it has input. Here your input is User.
To do that, you have to ask for all users. This is not practical bcz there might be thousand of users.

> Resource servers (applications or services serving protected resources) usually rely on some kind of information to decide if access should be granted to a protected resource. For RESTful-based resource servers, that information is usually obtained from a security token, usually sent as a bearer token on every request to the server. For web applications that rely on a session to authenticate users, that information is usually stored in a user’s session and retrieved from there for each request